# Generate a name list with consonants and vowel

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to generate a list of names like "ala", "oja", "kay", "zur"
instead of "nno","ooz","zii" but my functions is stuck in a infinite loop, whats wrong?

```
Function getName(num_letters As Integer) As List(Of String)
    Dim values As New List(Of String)
    Dim new_values As New List(Of String)
    Dim allChars() As Char = "aeiouykzrsdjlxvn".ToCharArray()
    For Each ch In allChars
        values.Add(ch.ToString())
    Next

    For i As Integer = 1 To num_letters - 1

        Dim istr As String = ""
        Dim word As String = ""
        Do
            For Each str As String In values

                istr = str
                For Each ch In allChars
                    If ("kzrsdjlxvn".IndexOf(ch.ToString()) >= 0) = True Then
                        'CONSONANTS
                        word = ch.ToString
                    Else
                        'VOWEL
                        word = ch.ToString
                    End If
                Next
            Next

        Loop Until (istr.Length + word.Length) = num_letters

        new_values.Add(istr + word)

    Next
    values = new_values

    Return values
End Function
```

Comment: The loop continues infinitely because word is always 1 character long and nothing is ever added to istr within the do loop

Comment: set a breakpoint and watch the code, compare what it really does versus what you expected it to do.  fix accordingly

Comment: @DavidWilson is correct - the value (istr.Length + word.Length) stays stuck at 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your approach to have it a bit simpler and more readable.

First I used an enumeration to distinguish between consonants and vowels:

```
Enum LetterType
    Consonant = 0
    Vowel = 1
End Enum
```

I use a Random object to select the different letters and randomize if I start with a consonant or vowel:

```
Private rnd As New Random()
```

Main Function. I added a new parameter numberOfNames since it was missing in your code. Additionally changed return type to IEnumerable(Of String) to hide implementation from interface.

```
Function getNames(numberOfLetters As Integer, numberOfNames As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim names As New List(Of String)
    Dim letterByType As New Dictionary(Of LetterType, String) From {
                                        {LetterType.Vowel, "aeiou"},
                                        {LetterType.Consonant, "kzrsdjlxvn"}
                                      }

    For j As Integer = 0 To numberOfNames - 1
        Dim nextLetterType As LetterType = rnd.Next(0, 2) 'Start with either consonant (0) or vowel (1)
        Dim currentName As String = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfLetters - 1
            currentName = String.Concat(currentName, getNextLetter(letterByType(nextLetterType)))
            nextLetterType = getNextLetterType(nextLetterType)
        Next
        names.Add(currentName)
    Next

    Return names
End Function
```

Returns the next random consonant or vowel:

```
Private Function getNextLetter(input As String) As Char
    Return input(rnd.Next(0, input.Length))
End Function
```

Returns the opposite of current LetterType to avoid "nno","ooz","zii":

```
Private Function getNextLetterType(currentLetterType As LetterType) As LetterType
    Return currentLetterType Xor 1
End Function
```

Testing it with

```
 For Each name As String In getName(3, 5)
      Console.WriteLine(name)
 Next
 Console.ReadLine()
```

shows e.g.

```
vod
zaj
rov
sov
vol
```

**EDIT**: Small improvements + typos

Comment: Your call to `rnd.Next(0, input.Length - 1)` should be `rnd.Next(0, input.Length)` as the second parameter is an **exclusive** upper bound. The same with the call to `rnd.Next(0, 1)` - it should be `rnd.Next(0, 2)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes my bad. I have edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I thought I might try to write a solution which will produce every possible combination rather than using random values which can cause duplicates.

Here's my code:

```
Function getName(num_letters As Integer) As List(Of String)

    Dim getAllSubsets As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of Char), IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Char))) = Nothing
    getAllSubsets = Function (xs) _
        If((xs Is Nothing OrElse Not xs.Any()), _
            Enumerable.Empty(Of IEnumerable(Of Char))(), _
            If(xs.Skip(1).Any(), _
                getAllSubsets(xs.Skip(1)).SelectMany(Function (ys) { ys, xs.Take(1).Concat(ys) }), _
                { Enumerable.Empty(Of Char)(), xs.Take(1) }))

    Dim consonants() As Char = "kzrsdjlxvn".ToCharArray()
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiouy".ToCharArray()

    Dim working_letters = (num_letters + num_letters Mod 2) \ 2

    Dim cSubsets = getAllSubsets(consonants).Where(Function (xs) xs.Count() = working_letters).ToArray()
    Dim vSubsets = getAllSubsets(vowels).Where(Function (xs) xs.Count() = working_letters).ToArray()

    Dim query = _
        From cs In cSubsets
        From vs In vSubsets
        From x In { String.Join("", cs.Zip(vs, Function (c, v) c & v)), String.Join("", vs.Zip(cs, Function (v, c) v & c)) }
        Order By x Ascending
        Select x.Substring(0, num_letters)

    Return query.Distinct().ToList()

End Function
```

Calling it with `getName(1)` I get back this:

> a, d, e, i, j, k, l, n, o, r, s, u, v, x, y, z

Calling it with `getName(2)` I get back this:

> ad, aj, ak, al, an, ar, as, av, ax, az, da, de, di, do, du, dy, ed, ej, ek, el, en, er, es, ev, ex, ez, id, ij, ik, il, in, ir, is, iv, ix, iz, ja, je, ji, jo, ju, jy, ka, ke, ki, ko, ku, ky, la, le, li, lo, lu, ly, na, ne, ni, no, nu, ny, od, oj, ok, ol, on, or, os, ov, ox, oz, ra, re, ri, ro, ru, ry, sa, se, si, so, su, sy, ud, uj, uk, ul, un, ur, us, uv, ux, uz, va, ve, vi, vo, vu, vy, xa, xe, xi, xo, xu, xy, yd, yj, yk, yl, yn, yr, ys, yv, yx, yz, za, ze, zi, zo, zu, zy

Calling it with `getName(3)` I get back this:

> ade, adi, ado, adu, ady, aje, aji, ajo, aju, ajy, ake, aki, ako, aku, aky, ale, ali, alo, alu, aly, are, ari, aro, aru, ary, ase, asi, aso, asu, asy, ave, avi, avo, avu, avy, axe, axi, axo, axu, axy, aze, azi, azo, azu, azy, daj, dal, dan, dav, dax, dej, del, den, dev, dex, dij, dil, din, div, dix, doj, dol, don, dov, dox, duj, dul, dun, duv, dux, edi, edo, edu, edy, eji, ejo, eju, ejy, eki, eko, eku, eky, eli, elo, elu, ely, eri, ero, eru, ery, esi, eso, esu, esy, evi, evo, evu, evy, exi, exo, exu, exy, ezi, ezo, ezu, ezy, ido, idu, idy, ijo, iju, ijy, iko, iku, iky, ilo, ilu, ily, iro, iru, iry, iso, isu, isy, ivo, ivu, ivy, ixo, ixu, ixy, izo, izu, izy, jal, jan, jav, jax, jel, jen, jev, jex, jil, jin, jiv, jix, jol, jon, jov, jox, jul, jun, juv, jux, kad, kaj, kal, kan, kar, kas, kav, kax, kaz, ked, kej, kel, ken, ker, kes, kev, kex, kez, kid, kij, kil, kin, kir, kis, kiv, kix, kiz, kod, koj, kol, kon, kor, kos, kov, kox, koz, kud, kuj, kul, kun, kur, kus, kuv, kux, kuz, lan, lav, lax, len, lev, lex, lin, liv, lix, lon, lov, lox, lun, luv, lux, odu, ody, oju, ojy, oku, oky, olu, oly, oru, ory, osu, osy, ovu, ovy, oxu, oxy, ozu, ozy, rad, raj, ral, ran, ras, rav, rax, red, rej, rel, ren, res, rev, rex, rid, rij, ril, rin, ris, riv, rix, rod, roj, rol, ron, ros, rov, rox, rud, ruj, rul, run, rus, ruv, rux, sad, saj, sal, san, sav, sax, sed, sej, sel, sen, sev, sex, sid, sij, sil, sin, siv, six, sod, soj, sol, son, sov, sox, sud, suj, sul, sun, suv, sux, udy, ujy, uky, uly, ury, usy, uvy, uxy, uzy, van, ven, vin, von, vun, xan, xav, xen, xev, xin, xiv, xon, xov, xun, xuv, zad, zaj, zal, zan, zar, zas, zav, zax, zed, zej, zel, zen, zer, zes, zev, zex, zid, zij, zil, zin, zir, zis, ziv, zix, zod, zoj, zol, zon, zor, zos, zov, zox, zud, zuj, zul, zun, zur, zus, zuv, zux

Calling it with `getName(4)` I get back this abbreviated list:

> adej, adel, aden, adev, ..., zury, zusy, zuvy, zuxy

And finally, calling it with `getName(12)` I get back this abbreviated list:

> adejiloxuvyn, akedijoluvyn, akedijoluxyn, ..., zasejiloxuvy, zasejixovuny, zaselixovuny

Comment: I like your non-duplicate approach. But with `getName(13)` the function gets to its limit ;)

Comment: @AlexB. - Yes, because there are no combinations that can possibly have 13 letters. So it almost instantly returns then correct empty set of results. If more than 12 letters is needed the number of vowels must increase. Thanks though. :-)